# How to save webpages from a list of links via terminal

Tags: curl, terminal

I have a list of links to webpages that I would like to download (preferable all into one txt).

So far everything was good, I was just doing this:

```
curl -o 1.txt "http://example.com/1"
curl -o 2.txt "http://example.com/2"
curl -o 3.txt "http://example.com/3"
...
```

and then combining them into one via terminal.

Worked well for few requests (up to about 100). But now I need over 1000 and server responds with "You are hitting our server quite a bit." or "Method may not be used".

**Is there any way or program to simply download HTML of pages that I have links to?**

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with wget?

Comment: So I tried. Server showed 403 error: Forbidden after 51 link... But thank you!

Comment: and trying to add `sleep` every X requests?